# Why is the /playsound command not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to check out the new sounds in Minecraft snapshot 15w49a, but when I type in the command, `/playsound minecraft:entity.squid.death @p,` it says that it played the sound, but I don't hear a thing! Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

This is because squids do not yet have a death sound.

Comment: Actually, if you read my message, you can tell that I'm in snapshot 15w49a. (actually 15w49b) The sounds are in the game, but they just don't play normally yet.

Comment: Oops. sorry. my bad. only the sound _events_ were added. not the sounds themselves sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

How recently have you tried this? A squid death sound does exist. If you are playing a specifically chosen version of Minecraft (**not latest version**), using mods, or have not formatted the command correctly, the death sound may not occur. The sound itself, in my opinion sounds like Dr. Zoidberg ( Lobster-man alien from Futurama) blowing his nose/facial tentacles.

Comment: Your answer reads like it was _partly_ copied from somewhere. If so, could you make it clearer which parts were your own and which were copied? Also, linking to the source is always appriciated.

Comment: If you read the comments of colorfusion's answer, you'll see that it was during snapshots where the sound event existed but the actual sound did not.

Answer (score -2):

/playsound minecraft:entity.squid.death @p X Y Z (source) (volume) (pitch) (minvolume)

The volume and XYZ is required in the version im using so you can try this
and the source is what the sound is masked as comng from so you can also turn down the volume of the playsound in the settings.

Comment: As the top answer suggests, squids don't have a death sound yet.